# AlertDialog recreating after Rotating

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Well I am trying to use Alertdialog from [Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). but there is a problem. if I rotate phone alert dialog is recreated and there are two alertdialog appears. How can prevent re and re create the alertDialog.

this is my code:

```
   public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
               .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       // User cancelled the dialog
                   }
               });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

and this is the showing method:

```
public void confirmFireMissiles() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "missiles");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `savedInstanceState` is set:

```
   public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // create new dialog
        }
   }
```

Comment: `if (savedInstanceState == null){// create new dialog}` I have put that code in `public void confirmFireMissiles()` and it works Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Add this

`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` property inside your `Activity` tag in manifest file.